# Urrlib request nothing happens python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello i made a small script. It should input a password to the (password input) on the website.
but when i run the script it doesn't give an error but also nothing happens. Where is my fault ?

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
pvn = "test12345"

dc = {"password":pvn}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(dc)
dataenc = data.encode("utf8")

u = urllib.request.urlopen \
("https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/basic/1/",dataenc)
li = u.readlines()

u.close()

for element in li:
    print(element)
```

when i watch the site it doesnt happen anything. I thought it would go to the next site and tell me wrong pw or right pw. so where can I see if this is the wrong or right pw ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, actually, provided I use correct indentation for the `for` loop.

Comment: I also got it to work with a little tweaking of the `for-loop` as Martijn suggested. (Also tweaked it to work with `Python 2.7`).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix your `for-loop` like so:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
pvn = "test12345"

dc = {"password":pvn}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(dc)
dataenc = data.encode("utf8")

u = urllib.request.urlopen \
("https://www.hackthissite.org/missions/basic/1/",dataenc)
li = u.readlines()

u.close()

for element in li:
    print(element)
```

These are the annoying things in programming that will kill hours of your time :)

Comment: hey could u take a look on my answer forget to set it as reply

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: hey when i run the script i dont see the answer of the website. So i want to know where can I see if this was the right or wrong password. or to say it other where can I see the answer from the website to my request

Comment: This is technically a separate question from what you've originally asked. You should accept the answer that was given here (if it answered your original question), and post the new question for this new issue.

Comment: ive already done this but noone has answered. could u tell me the answer ?

Comment: Nobody responded to [your follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440960/where-can-i-see-the-answer-of-the-site-with-urllib-request-python-3-3) because it wasn't at all clear what you were asking. Secondly, your question here was re-edited to be a completely different question from the original post. You're not exactly following the procedures of the community with respect to clarity, code formatting, and responses/answers. As such people will be less likely to help. Restructure your questions, accept answers that helped, and *try* to be conscious of code formats.